# C++ WebRequest Response

Tags: c++, sockets, http, response, webrequest

I am coding a program that creates a WebRequest to a url in C++. This is my code:

```
void CreateRequest()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
        return;
    }
    SOCKET Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    struct hostent *host;
    host = gethostbyname("www.website.net");
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    SockAddr.sin_port = htons(80);
    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);
    if (connect(Socket, (SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0){
        return;
    }
    const char link[] = "www.website.net";

    char Link[100] = "";
    strcat(Link, "GET /File.php?Test=");
    strcat(Link, "test");
    strcat(Link, " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.website.net \r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n");


    send(Socket, Link, strlen(Link), 0);

    char buffer[10000];
    int nDataLength;
    while ((nDataLength = recv(Socket, buffer, 10000, 0)) > 0){
        int i = 0;
        while (buffer[i] >= 32 || buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == '\r') {
            cout << buffer[i];
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    closesocket(Socket);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

What I want to do is just get "Accesss denied" so I can check the request state from my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
strcat(Link, " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.website.net \r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n")
```

You have an extra space between the host name and the \r\n. Try removing that so it looks like:

```
strcat(Link, " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.website.net\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n")
```

Edit:

It's also entirely possible that everything at the HTTP level is working fine, but the PHP file on the server is generating the "Access Denied" message. Do you have control over the PHP file?

Comment: The code is working fine, "Access denied" is normal as output, but I just want this one, without "HTTP/\.\ 200 OK... " etc. etc. So when I execute the request I just want to have the response from the page "Access denied."

Comment: Then you'll need to parse the response to get the response body (everything after `\r\n\r\n`). BTW -- this response is a little bogus; it has `Content-Type: text/html` but the body is clearly in plain text.

Comment: That's the problem, I never worked with parsing and I have no idea on how to do that.

Comment: The HTTP protocol is deceptively complex with many subtleties. You'd be much better off finding an existing C++ library for building the requests and parsing the responses.

Comment: I used Curl Library time ago, but I don't want my program to have additional dlls.